# Проблема с кодировкой import.sql c springboot 2.x в Oracle

Tags: java, spring-boot, oracle11g

При запуске приложения, происходит также запуск скрипта, который содержит в себе INSERT

**src/main/resources/application.properties**

```sql
INSERT INTO COMPANY (id, ADDRESS, CONTACT_FIRST_NAME, CONTACT_LAST_NAME, CONTACT_PHONE, NAME, PHONE) VALUES (2, 'ул.Высокая', 'Alex', 'Saturn', '+7 911 456-75-45', 'mountain', '+1 45');
```

Но значение столбца с киррилицей вставляется неправильно, происходит нарушение кодировки

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Установка

```
spring.datasource.connectionProperties=useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf-8;autoReconnect=true;useSSL=false
spring.datasource.sql-script-encoding=UTF-8
```

не решает проблемы.

У меня настроена консоль с нужной кодировкой (я модифицировал реестр), через консоль sqlplus, все вставляется нормально, без нарушения кодировки...

Через Sql Developer, через консоль,  также происходит нарушение кодировки...

В качестве предположения, могу сказать, что вставка значений в таблицу, которые **Spring** автоматически берет из файла **import.sql** (который расположен в classpath), происходит минуя Hibernate и скорей всего обращение идет напрямую к **JDBC-драйверу**.

Потому что, если вставка происходит через получение запроса к rest-контроллеру, тогда киррилица корректно записывается в таблицу (использую Java 8).

Как это можно исправить и почему так происходит?

Comment: Возможно кодировка файла import.sql отлична от utf-8

Comment: точно нет, все файлы в проекте имеют UTF-8, я в среде разработки обязательно это указываю

Comment: Вы забыли указать кодировку установленную в БД.